# Create a numpy memmap for a large Repeat Python Numpy memmap for binary file

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap, memmap

I am trying to construct a memory map file for a large binary file where I give it a dictionary of dtypes, offsets, and shapes and want it to repeat for a specified amount.  Is there a way to do this like you can in the Matlab memmapfile.m?  Thanks!

so far I have the following but I only get the first record and I need to repeat it 798 more times throughout the file.

```py
numpy.memmap(fileName,dtype=float,mode='r',offset=511,shape=(2,1))
```

I get the first array of data for that datatype but I need to repeat it 798 more times within the file.

Comment: Are you trying to get a 798x2x1 array as a result?  Shouldn't you make the shape `(798,2,1)`?

Comment: i think you are asking about the `repeat` parameter in matlab and whether we have a similar one in python ... you can use Tim Roberts suggestion and just add the repeat number in the first dimension.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, what exactly is the repeat parameter doing in matlab?  Is it just repeating the structure I give it 798 times?  , yes the end result will be a 798x2x1

Comment: Thanks Tim, yes the end result will be a 798x2x1, but really I have a dictionary of formats, offsets, and shapes that I want repeated 798 times in the file.  If I did that would it get all the correct data in the order I need?ideally my dtype would be {Names: ("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"),formats: (double, int, 'single', int, int, int), offsets: (512, 520, 528, 556,4556, 8556), shapes: ((1,1),(2,1),(7,1),(1,1000), (1,1000), (1,1000)} I can do this once and I get the right results but I don't know how to go through the rest of the file and get the other 797.

Comment: Hi, I added the repeat number in the first dimension but that didn't work.